# Filtering issue with ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icollectionview

`ImageAlbums` is an `ICollectionView` type and `GlobalCollection.MyImageAlubms` is an `ObservableCollection<T>` type.

```
ImageAlbums = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GlobalCollection.MyImageAlubms);
ImageAlbums.Filter = new Predicate<object>(this.FilterImageAlbumList);
```

In a view I'm using ImageAlbums for showing a filtered image list. I have filtered the list using `FilterImageAlbumList` method. The problem is I have used the `GlobalCollection.MyImageAlubms` in another place. In that view I have used the GlobalCollection.MyImageAlubms directly as source but in there the list are being showed as filtered also. I am also providing the filter method here, following code represents the filter method

```
private bool FilterImageAlbumList(object item)
{
    AlbumModel albumMoel = (AlbumModel)item;
    if(LOGIC_OF_FILTERING)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there any way to filter only `ImageAlbums` without affecting the GlobalCollection. FYI - I won't deep copy the Global Collection.

Comment: Since item is an object you can test the type.  Each class has a different enumeration for type.

Comment: You can create a new view with  `new CollectionViewSource { Source = GlobalCollection.MyImageAlubms}.View;` however I've found this buggy in the past (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166747/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-presentationframework) and ended up just creating copies...

Comment: @Joe, if you found this buggy why you are suggesting this ?

Comment: @lukai that's why I put it as a comment, not an answer. Just giving options. Someone else might suggest it as an answer without knowing it's faults.

Comment: @Joem thanks. Got the solution already though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by these two facts:

1. Each collection instance has **only one** default (instance of the) view, thus `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` always returns the same instance for the same argument
2. *WPF* binding mechanism does not bind directly to a collection, but to its default collection view

So if you set a filter on the default view, its effects are visible wherever you bind to the collection.

If you want a separate instance of an `ICollectionView` your best bet is to instantiate it manually. For `ObservableCollection<T>` a good choice is `ListCollectionView`. So this should resolve your problems:

```
ImageAlbums = new ListCollectionView(GlobalCollection.MyImageAlubms);
```